# how to capture a video using a rtsp link using node.js

Tags: node.js, rtsp, onvif

i have a rtsp link and i need to in some moments capture few seconds and save that file in my computer like a mp4 file or something like

i tried to use that code but doesnt worked for me

```
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

// RTSP stream URL
const streamUrl = 'mycamlink';

// Output file path
const outputPath = 'output.mp4';

// Create the FFmpeg command
const command = ffmpeg(streamUrl)
  .inputOptions('-rtsp_transport', 'tcp')
  .outputOptions('-c', 'copy')
  .outputOptions('-flags', '+global_header')
  .output(outputPath);

console.log('Recording started.');

// Start recording
command.run();

// Stop recording after 10 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  command.kill();
  console.log('Recording stopped.');
}, 10000);
```

that give me this error
Error: Cannot find ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

You might not have ffmpeg installed on your machine. The `fluent-ffmpeg` is just a node wrapper on the local ffmpeg instance.

You can install it by running (if on MacOS):
`brew install ffmpeg`

The `fluent-ffmpeg` Github repo has a prerequisites section that might be helpful:

https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg?tab=readme-ov-file#prerequisites